# Store UTF-8 PHP Array in MySQL without serialize() or json_encode()

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

`serialize()` outputs unnecessary garbage like string length and other things, which is completely useless.

```
a:2:{s:10:"SOME VALUE";a:35:{s:36:"VAL1";s:1:"1";s:7: skipped...............
```

`json_encode()` is better, but still does garbage.

```
{"SOME VALUE":{"\u041a\u043e\u0434 \u041c\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0430 \u041f\u043e\u044f\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f":"1","\u0415-\u0414\u0422":"0","\u0420\u0435\u0436\u0438\u043c \u041e\u0431\u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0438":"0","\u041c\u0430\u0440\u0448\u0440\u0443\u0442":"0","\u041a\u043e\u043c\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0430\u0440\u0438\u0439":"0","\u041e\u0442\u0432. \u0418\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b
```

Why do I need all this stuff instead of readable array? MySQL field is already set to `utf8_unicode_ci`.

As the result I get an absolutely unnecessary traffic.

What are my options instead of manual parsing?

Code wont matter here.

Comment: he info youre talking about form searialize isnt useless, its kind of necessary in order to it to be unserialized....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is short and simple.
Do not store serialized arrays in database.

Even if you think you don't need any search of filtering or relational linking for the stored data at the moment, in a few days you will realize that you need that, yet unable to distinguish even smallest value in this blob.

So, create a regular table for the data and store every value in a separate field.
And you will have your data exactly the way you want it - sound and safe.

Comment: Thought about is one more time... Really, what the hell? I will create a separate table and spread it all there...

Answer (score 1):

PHP 4 and 5 do not have built-in Unicode support; In this case I use this function for unserializing data. Serialize function works OK.

```
/**
 * Mulit-byte Unserialize
 *
 * UTF-8 will screw up a serialized string
 *
 * @access private
 * @param string
 * @return string
 */
function mb_unserialize($string) {
    $string = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!se', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $string);
    return unserialize($string);
}
```

Source: http://dzone.com/snippets/mulit-byte-unserialize

Answer (score 1):

In php 5.4 `json_encode` supports an additional option flag: `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`.
You would use it as follows:

```
$encoded = json_encode($array,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

This would not escape utf8 sequences (`\u041a` etc).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

This requires that you use PHP version >= 5.4 of course.

**Please note:  As a general rule storing serialised data in your database is considered bad practice**